# Trying to compare now time to a time in a file

Tags: python, datetime

I am new to Python and programming in general but I'm willing to learn. I am trying to open a file that just has a time stamp inside of it. I want to take that time in the file and compare it to the now time. 
I think my issue is I am not converting the incoming string to the right format. Any help would be excellent and help me learn.

-D

`

```
from datetime import datetime

# get current time
now = datetime.now()
print("Current time: ", now)

filePathLastUpdated = '/Users/dmurray/Desktop/printer folder test/LastUpDated.txt'
lastUpdated = open(filePathLastUpdated, "r")

print("last updated time: ", lastUpdated.read())

if lastUpdated.read() < now:
    print("not up to date")
else:
    print("up to date")`
```

the text in the file is
"2020-05-20 09:51:28.874028"

Comment: Update your question by adding what exactly is inside the txt file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: added exactly what is in that file I am reading from. D

Answer (score 0):

There is a great date utility package called [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which provides invaluable help when working with dates. Among other things, it can parse your date into a `datetime` object which can be compared to others. `datetime` objects naturally are comparable. Once you have the right type, you're good to go!

```py
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

now = datetime.datetime.now()
not_now = dateutil.parser.parse("2020-05-20 09:51:28.874028")

updated = not_now >= now
```

Another option is combining [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with the expected [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) of the "stringed" date to produce a similar `datetime` object.
But, I highly recommend having [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a de-facto package for working with dates.